# Simple library in Android : Boolean in "1" or "0"

Tags: android, simple-framework

Simple library is great and i already parsed many 
different XML from soap servers since last 3 days, but i encountered 
boolean attributes with "0" or "1" :

```
<list mybool1="0" mybool2="1" attr1="attr" attr2="attr">
    <page mybool3="1">
        ...
    </page>
    <page mybool3="0">
        ...
    </page>
    ...
</list>
```

I tried to create this class :

```
public class Boolean01Converter implements Converter<Boolean>
{
    @Override
    public Boolean read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
        return new Boolean(node.getValue().equals("1"));
    }
    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, Boolean value) throws Exception {
        node.setValue(value.booleanValue()?"1":"0");
    }
}
```

and implemented it on my object definition :

```
@Root(name="list")
public class ListFcts
{
    @Attribute
    @Convert(Boolean01Converter.class)
    private Boolean mybool1;

    @Attribute
    @Convert(Boolean01Converter.class)
    private Boolean mybool2;

    @Attribute
    private int ...

    @ElementList(name="page", inline=true)
    private List<Page> pages;

    public Boolean getMybool1() {
        return mybool1;
    }
}
```

But i still get false for every boolean.

`[edit]`
In fact, when i do this :

```
@Override
public Boolean read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
    return true;
}
```

i still get `false` for :

```
Serializer serial = new Persister();
ListFcts listFct = serial.read(ListFcts.class, soapResult);
if(listFct.getMybool1())
{
    //this never happens
}else{
    //this is always the case
}
```

so my Converter has no impact...

Also : how can I attach the converter to the Persister instead of 
declaring it on @Attributes hundred times ?

Many thanks in advance !!

`[edit2]`

i give up with Converter, this is my own solution :

```
@Root(name="list")
public class ListFcts
{
    @Attribute
    private int mybool1;

    @Attribute
    private int mybool2;

    public int getMybool1() {
        return mybool1;
    }

    public Boolean isMybool1() {
        return (mybool1==1)?true:false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i gave up with Converter, I heard about Transform but didn't find how to use it so this is my own basic solution :

```
@Root(name="list")
public class ListFcts
{
    @Attribute
    private int mybool1;

    @Attribute
    private int mybool2;

    public int getMybool1() {
        return mybool1;
    }

    public Boolean isMybool1() {
        return (mybool1==1)?true:false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using `node.getValue()` which returns the *value* (read: contents) of each XML node (the "..." bit in your examples).

What you need is to reading the attribute values, something like `node.getAttributeValue("mybool1").equals("1")`

Comment: I just checked the behavior of new Boolean(String) and Boolean.valueOf(String) with the values of "0" and "1" ... it does not parse those. Follow the method above to resolve this.

Comment: or maybe i can use a switch statement ?

Comment: Maybe using NodeMap<InputNode> boolAttr = node.getAttributes();

Comment: I edited my code since the problem is elsewhere !! see last lines

Comment: They shouldn't be attributes if the attribute names aren't known.

Comment: attributes are known, but there are many of them... how can i distinguish them ?

Comment: I give up with converter for such a simple element ! see code in main message

Comment: can you show me an usage of node.getAttributeValue("mybool1").equals("1") since there are many boolean attribute ? i can't figure it out... thanks ^^